# scrolling using down arrow in Jquery autocomplete result issues (scrollbar always go to top)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete functionality in search box & in result i am using 
position: { my : "left bottom", at: "left top", collision: "flip flip" }
But when select result using down key arrow result is selected.
Issues is scrollbar always tends to top. its not down according to result.

Comment: Can you provide the least amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem?

Comment: $("#input_text_box_id").autocomplete({
 appendTo: "#div_result_id",
 position: { my : "left bottom", at: "left top", collision: "flip flip" },
 source: function( request, response ) {
 $.ajax({
   url: 'jsonPageUrl',
   data: {
    featureClass: "P",
    style: "full",
    maxRows: 12,
    name_startsWith: request.term
   },
   success: function(msg) {       
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    response( $.map( data.value, function( item ) {
     return {
      label: item.title,
      value: item.name       
     }
    }));
   }
  });
 },
 minLength: 0,
 scroll:true
});